# Append to vertical accordion on button click jquery

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a horizontal tabs, and inside that, I have a vertical tab functionality. In the vertical tab, I have provided a button called `Add More` like this:

```
<button id="addMore" type="button">Add More</button>
```

On click of the button, I want to append new tab to the previous one.

click method on the button:

```
$('#addMore').on('click', function() {
    $('#vtabs ul li').last().append('<li><a href="#option1">Option 1</a></li>');
    $('#vtabs div').last().append('<div id="option1">dsg</div>');

    $("#vtabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
    $("#vtabs > ul > li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
});
```

Html Part:

```
<div id = "htabs-outer">
    <h1>htabs-outer</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#htab-outer-2">Horizontal Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id = "htab-outer-2">
        <h2>Htab outer 2 content</h2>
        <div id="vtabs">
            <h1>Vtabs</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#vtab-1">Vertical Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#vtab-2">Vertical Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#vtab-3">Vertical Tab 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="vtab-1">
                <h2>Vtab 1 content</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="vtab-2">
                <h2>Vtab 2 content</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="vtab-3">
                <h2>Vtab 3 content</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="addMore" type="button">Add More</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This does appends to the last `li` element, but does not function it properly.

I want that if the button is clicked, it should append to the vertical tab and should also append its corresponding `div`.

What is the mistake that I have made ?

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zucbpe3o/) that you can have a look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use `after()` to add the new tab, as `append()` is placing it inside the existing tab structure, which is incorrect. Secondly, you also need to call `refresh` on the tabs to add the required styling and events. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#htabs-outer").tabs();

    var $vtabs = $('#vtabs').tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
    $vtabs.find('> ul > li').removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");

    $('#addMore').on('click', function () {
        $vtabs
            .find('ul li:last').after('<li><a href="#option1">Option 1</a></li>').end()
            .find('div:last').after('<div id="option1">dsg</div>').end()
            .tabs('refresh').addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix").end()
            .find("> ul > li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5LeL2hf1/)

Also note that your `click` handler should be inside the `$(function() {})` handler.